# Send email "After a webform has been submitted" to submitter

Tags: 7, webforms, rules

I'm using Drupal 7.97 with these modules:

- Views 4.25
- Rules 2.13
- Webform rules 1.6

Recently I upgraded Drupal to 7.97 and Views to 4.x branch, After that my rule that sends email to anyone who submitted the webform stopped working.

My rule reacts on the event "**After a webform has been submitted**" and should fire the action:
"Send email" to `<?php print $data['components']['email']['value'][0]; ?>`.

***email** above is my email field from Webform "Contact".*

I've debugged this variable: `$data['components']['email']['value'][0]` and it contains proper email after submitting the form.

But in dblog I've found the message:
`Error sending e-mail (from myname@site.com to ).`

What I've tried:

- updated webform_rules.info from `dependencies[] = webform (>=7.x-3.x)` to `dependencies[] = webform`
- applied the patch: https://www.drupal.org/files/issues/webform_rules-submission_rule_firing-patch_5_fix-1964590-15.patch from [Multipage webform with conditionals not firing rule upon submission](https://www.drupal.org/node/1964590#comment-9143817)
- tried to use: `<?php print $data['components']['email'][0]; ?>`

Here is my rule export

```
{ "rules_after_submitting_contact_form" : {
    "LABEL" : "After submitting contact form",
    "PLUGIN" : "reaction rule",
    "OWNER" : "rules",
    "TAGS" : [ "After submitting contact form" ],
    "REQUIRES" : [ "php", "rules", "webform_rules" ],
    "ON" : { "webform_rules_submit" : [], "webform_rules_submit_as_draft" : [] },
    "DO" : [
      { "mail" : {
          "to" : "\u003C?php print $data[\u0027components\u0027][\u0027email\u0027][\u0027value\u0027][0]; ?\u003E",
          "subject" : "information",
          "message" : "Thank you for submitting contact form",
          "from" : "user@site.com",
          "language" : [ "" ]
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```